# IK rig breaks when I add a pole target

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I've been trying to do rigging recently, and when I add a pole target to my IK rig, my character's foot just slides up and down the leg, which remains stiff. I've had this problem for a while and I have no idea how to fix it. I have a link to a video to show exactly what's going on: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qHK51yggU4sGDHTB-A6aoSrFe8iFpfQZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I'm answering my own question because I figured out the issue myself and in case anyone else has the same question they can come here for an answer if they find this.

The issue was that the rig didn't know where to bend the limb at since it was straight, which was why the leg was completely stiff. The legs need to be slightly bent so that the rig knows where exactly to bend it at.

Comment: A nice trick is to add a driver after rotating the bone a bit. That way reseting rotation (Alt R) won't affect it.